# Error when adding Entity Framework query to datasource for a DataGrid View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, datagrid

I am trying to add a data source to a `DataGridView` in ASP.NET, here is the error I'm getting:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
using (MSAAnalyserEntities entities = new MSAAnalyserEntities())
{
    UniRecView.DataSource = (from TableRecord in entities.TableRecords where TableRecord.Sector == "University" select TableRecord).ToList();
    UniRecView.DataBind();
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that the `GridView` will display records from my database only if and when a specific column "Sector" has the data "University" in its column.

I can't seem to fix this error, please could you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The real reason of the exception is inside thru exception. you need to look for innerexception property of this exception and check is message. That should telk what exact sql issue is breaking the things.

Comment: Thank you I have solved this issue.